# How to keep focus on control intact while AJAX fills DropDown?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, ext.net

I am using Ext.Net 1.3 library for ASP.NET.

I have five ComboBox controls and each is linked to the other. Selection in the first ComboBox is compulsory. Selecting an item from the first fills the second ComboBox, and so on.

The problem is when I press TAB key to navigate on the controls, the focus is lost after appearing for some time on the next Combo.

This is because, when the first Combo looses focus, it fires the `OnSelectedValueChanged` event which executes the code to fill the second ComboBox using AJAX.

How to keep the focus intact even while AJAX request is executed?

Comment: Seems like you have to override this behavior of ComboBox. If you will post example of your code I will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

One option may be to call .Focus() on the triggering ComboBox from within your `OnSelectedValueChanged` event handler.

This will force the focus to be reset on the ComboBox after the DirectEvent returns.

Hope this helps.